# Retrieving visible data from Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am currently using Datatables to display three columns with a varying number of rows of information.

The table is setup so that when a column header is clicked the table is sorted in reference to that column. I am trying to use fnGetData to get the visible data that is now sorted. However, my attempt simply returns the original data the table was initialized with.

This is a roughly what the code looks like:

```
$("#example").click(function() {
           oTable = $('#' + tableName).dataTable();

              var secondCellArray=[];
              $.each( oTable.fnGetData(), function(i, row){
                  secondCellArray.push( row[0],row[1],row[2]);
            })

             console.log( secondCellArray)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The `fnGetData` method is the correct (for Datatables version <= 1.10) way to extract data:

http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnGetData

Per that documentation that function will:

> Get the data for the whole table, an individual row or an individual
>   cell based on the provided parameters.

Here's an example from that documentation:

```
oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

oTable.$('tr').click( function () {
   var data = oTable.fnGetData( this );
   // ... do something with the array / object of data for the row
});
```

---

NOTE: My original answer mentioned using `fnGetData` without an argument (which worked for me a long time ago), and the docs suggest that should still work ("the data for the whole table"), but since that answer got down-voted and documentation doesn't specifically provide an example of its usage, I'm going to avoid recommending using it that way.

---

Of course, the old Datatables is kind of terrible, so most likely (unless you have a lot of code built around the old Datables) your best bet is to upgrade to the newest version (or to another table/grid library entirely).

Answer (score -1):

The underscrore (_) method is particularly useful here. It's worked well for me in the past. It will return an array of objects.

```
oTable._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
```