# How to get searched rows from Datatables at API function call context

Tags: javascript, datatables

JSFiddle for this question: http://jsfiddle.net/nhg5ej4s/

I use the 1.10.15 version of Datatables.

I have this `sum()` function registered in API:

```
 $.fn.dataTable.Api.register('sum()', function () {
     var data = this.flatten().toArray();
     return data.reduce(function (a, b) {
         return (a * 1) + (b * 1); // cast strings
     }, 0);
 });
```

When I need to use this function, for example, in [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option for update totals in footer (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhg5ej4s/) for context):

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function (settings) {
       var api = this.api();
       $(api.column(5).footer()).html('Total: ' + api.column(5).data().sum());
    }
});
```

The function works, but when I apply filter on the table with any search, the values passed to `sum()` take all rows, not that filtered by search.

There is a way to identify the search context inside the `sum()` function?

**PS:** While writing this questions, I realize that I can pass a option in column call that will filter only searched rows: `api().column(5, {'search': 'applied'}).data().sum()` but I decide to keep the question to know if there is a way to do this inside the `sum()` code. [JSFidlle with this update](http://jsfiddle.net/ops7w7v9/)

Comment: Honestly, the 'search' : 'applied' is your best bet, especially if you get into pagination. You can look at this for other ideas though if you really want to add something in your sum() function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915988/retrieving-row-data-after-filtering-jquery-datatables

Comment: I agree with you @Woodrow. If you want to put this as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the 'search' : 'applied' is your best bet, especially if you get into pagination. You can look at this for other ideas though if you really want to add something in your sum() function: [Retrieving row data after filtering JQuery Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915988/retrieving-row-data-after-filtering-jquery-datatables)